# Integer solutions to an exponential equation $2^x\pm2=5^y$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, exponential-function, diophantine-equations

Are there any integer solutions for the equation
$$2^x+2=5^y$$
Similarly, are there any solutions to 
$$2^x-2=5^y$$
I ask the second because I'm not sure if they are answered similarly.
Put qualitatively, are there any powers of 2 and 5 that are exactly 2 apart?

Comment: Oh! Of course. Then, as a follow-up, would you know any method of approaching this if the equation was 3^x as opposed to 2^x?

Comment: $3^3-2=27-2 = 25 = 5^2$.  I would expect there are many others as well, but do not have a proof yet in mind.  If the question was about $3^x \pm 3 = 5^y$, in a similar fashion to the earlier situation, $3^x\pm 3 \equiv 0\mod 3$ however $5^y\not\equiv 0\mod 3$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The left side is even if $x>0$. If $x$ is $0$, there is no solution. If $x<0$ then $1<2^x+2<5$ and $2^x-2<0$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $x$ and $y$ are positive the answer is no. All powers of $5$ end in $5$. Powers of $2$ end in $2,4,6,8$. Since adding or subtracting $2$ to any of those will not result in $5$ the left hand side never ends in $5$ while the right hand side always does and the two are never equal.